# Offline maps with markers

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

I have a requirement to create a web based application, which is hosted on a intranet server(no internet access). This application will be used to keep track of various status over in the various geographical location, the locations are currently spanned within Asia.

I have read up on google map api, and it seems that it is against their policy to use their map offline. On the other hand, the custom markers is something that I am interested in. I am considering to make use of the marker concept to show the status of the area.

Hence sample example of the status can be denoted by having red as error, green as working properly, and this will be updated every 1 hour.

Any bros have done similar concept and will be willing to guide me? The offline maps is preferred to be free, however if a paid version proves to be useful, it can be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could use a combination of MapServer as mapping server and openstreetmap as data source (maps for asia are available, but it depends on the level of zoom, precision and update you are willing to work with) and OpenLayers  to load, display and render your markers and data.

Links :

- MapServer :http://mapserver.org/index.html
- OpenStreetMap : http://www.openstreetmap.org/
- OpenLayers : http://openlayers.org/

Notice : you can find .shp versions of openstreetmap for offline viewing and usage, free of charges, here : http://downloads.cloudmade.com/ , and here : http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/

And here is a MapServer Tutorial for C# mapscript (ASP .NET) : http://www.paolocorti.net/2006/09/20/mapserver-tutorial-for-c-mapscript-asp-net/

Comment: thanks for the information. I do see that the demo in the internet website seems slow in rendering. If this is put to intranet use, will this performance be better? License wise, do you have any idea, as I will be implementing into a business environment.

Comment: The speed depend of the amount of data you'll be using as well as the infrastructure you'll deploy on.
As for the license, MapServer is released under the X/MIT License. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License), so you won't have problems using it on your intranet for commercial uses.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will take your answer and see if it works out fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps/Earth will only allow you to store 2Gb of map data locally. The API will not let you store any at all. There is no way to use the maps offline. However you can try downloading images from NASA World Wind: http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/ it is opensource.

Comment: I see that it works with java, which I will not be able to convince my superior as we are a Microsoft biased company.