# How to overlay Longitude & latitude markers on JPG map?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, maps

I need to be able to show markers (polygons) on a few maps that are JPG's that are various zoom level looks at same thing.

I would normally use google maps for this, but **I cannot rely on the mobile device having access to the internet** when needed, thus need to use a locally stored set of JPG's and overlay the items on it, preferably with some sort of interaction such as click/touch for more detail popup/modal.

Has anybody made anything similar to this that uses the GEO location but not the internet of a mobile device, and locally stored long/lat details?  Can you give me any pointers?

Comment: There is a similar question but for C#, maybe you get some insights from there http://stackoverflow.com/q/8752950/914874

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CATiledLayer for displaying and overlaying marks.Here is a nice tutorial
[Here](http://blog.jcmultimedia.com.au/2012/02/catiledlayer-melbourne-cocoaheads-february-2012/)